# Odoo 9.0 Hiding columns in the table

Tags: odoo-9

I'm trying to make dropdown list with columns' headers that have functionality, which lets you hide or show the column in the table just by clicking. I'd like to ask, if there is any possibility to hide/show columns(fields) in the Odoo's table dynamically?

I have tried with field_view_get, but it wont work. It's just "undefined".

Answer (score 0):

Tree view columns can be hidden statically in the field definition

`<field name="description" invisible="1"/>`

The column values can be hidden dynamically

`<field name="description" attrs="{'invisible': [('hide_description', '=', True)]'"/>`

As far as I know, it's not possible to hide the entire column dynamically. You might be able to achieve it with JS or by using the **Action** menu to load a wizard to show/hide columns where the "Apply" button on the wizard actually manipulates a `ir.ui.view` for the user?